# How to modify UI in notification flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-android, just-audio, flutter-notification, audio-service

I'm making a music player application by following this [tutorial](https://suragch.medium.com/background-audio-in-flutter-with-audio-service-and-just-audio-3cce17b4a7d) using packages from

```
 audio_service: ^0.18.4
 just_audio: ^0.9.20
```

the music player app runs smoothly, but I want to add a button in the notification view section, is there a way to do it?
if must be write in native Android side, there is documentation maybe? thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a flutter expert, but I believe installing a *third-party library* would give you an answer, more specifically the `awesome notifications` 's `Notifications with action buttons` section.

I've found this website and this video, which in my opinion is very useful. The reason behind this is that I learned based on this video too and was able to make awesome things, so I think it could help you too!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JAq9fVn3X7U

https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications

I believe their discord server (mentioned in the above article) has a very helpful community, I think you could get a more professionally appropriate answer than from me.

Comment: Hi!
You should always be clear that your solution involves installing a third party library. 
I suggest you reword it like 'This can be achieved using the awesome_notifications library'.

Many developers prefer to only install the minimum dependencies necessary.

Comment: Hi, I modified the comment, thank you for your suggestion!